# Double Select into NOT IN

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT on (i.empleado) i.id as id,i.dia as dia,e.id as empleadoId,pe.nombre as personaNombre,pe.apellido1 as personaApellido1,pe.apellido2 personaApellido2 FROM rrhh.imputacion as i 
INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = i.empleado 
JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = i.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
WHERE p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2  and e.id 
NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT on (i.empleado) i.empleado FROM rrhh.imputacion as i 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = i.empleado 
 JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = i.id 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
 WHERE i.dia >= '2017-12-04' AND i.dia <= '2017-12-10' and p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2 
 ORDER  BY i.empleado, i.dia DESC,i.id
)
ORDER  BY i.empleado, i.dia DESC,i.id)
t
ORDER BY t.dia DESC
```

I need to add the query below in the "NOT IN", with an OR:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (a.empleado) a.empleado FROM rrhh.ausencia as a 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = a.empleado 
 JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = a.id 
 INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
 WHERE a.dia >= '2017-12-04' AND a.dia <= '2017-12-11' and p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2 
 ORDER  BY a.empleado, a.dia DESC,a.id
```

There should be something similar to what I put down, but that does not work, because I do not know the syntax, I tried an OR and a UNION, but in both cases I get an error:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT on (i.empleado) i.id as id,i.dia as dia,e.id as empleadoId,pe.nombre as personaNombre,pe.apellido1 as personaApellido1,pe.apellido2 personaApellido2 FROM rrhh.imputacion as i 
INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = i.empleado 
JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = i.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
WHERE p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2  and e.id 
NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT on (i.empleado) i.empleado FROM rrhh.imputacion as i 
INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = i.empleado 
JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = i.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
WHERE i.dia >= '2017-12-04' AND i.dia <= '2017-12-10' and p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2 
ORDER  BY i.empleado, i.dia DESC,i.id
OR -- UNION   
SELECT DISTINCT on (a.empleado) a.empleado FROM rrhh.ausencia as a 
INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = a.empleado 
JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = a.id 
INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
WHERE a.dia >= '2017-12-04' AND a.dia <= '2017-12-11' and p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2 
ORDER  BY a.empleado, a.dia DESC,a.id   
 )
ORDER  BY i.empleado, i.dia DESC,i.id)
t
ORDER BY t.dia DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `I need to add the query below in the "NOT IN", with an OR:`

I don't know what you mean by "with an OR". If you mean that `e.id` should be `NOT IN` the first subquery OR not in the second subquery, you could do:

```
...
AND (
    e.id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ...
    ) OR (
    e.id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ...
    )
)
```

If you don't want it to be in either (hence the attempt at a union) just change the OR to AND.

Although I suspect the query plan for this query will be quite poor. IN and NOT IN are inefficient when there are lots of results in there.

Also the code is quite strange. Most of your joins are explicitly INNER JOINs, but a couple just say JOIN. But JOIN by default is an INNER JOIN. So why are some lines explicit and others implicit? And why the difference in styles throughout the code? Case in point, `AS` vs `as`, from one line to the next...

Comment: I want everyone, except what is one or both subselect. So I need an AND.
Thank you very much.